# Expressão Regular para separar Substring da String

Tags: php, regex, php-7

Tenho a seguinte frase `"SUZANO ZANO ZMES ZDIA ZANO_MES"` e preciso retirar dela somente `"ZANO ZMES ZDIA"`, lembrando que o `ZANO` de `SUZANO` e de `ZANO_MES` não podem ser relacionados.

Usei a seguinte expressão e ainda os resultados não são ideais : `/[^A-Z]Z[A-Z0-9^_]+/`

Consegui melhorar um pouco a expressão desta forma : `/^A-Za-z ]Z[A-Z0-9]+[^_ ]/` mas ainda não sei se é o jeito correto.

A regra é pegar tudo que começa com `"Z"`, que não anteceda por letras, números e caracteres especiais e que não contenha o `"_"`.

Comment: Qual a regra que define quais palavras serão removidas? Serão sempre estas? Ou só todas excetos as primeira e última? Ou o que?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quer tudo que começa com "Z", uma alternativa é:

```
$texto = "SUZANO ZANO ZMES ZDIA ZANO_MES";
if (preg_match_all('/\bZ[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b/', $texto, $resultados)) {
    foreach($resultados[0] as $str) {
        echo "$str\n";
    }
}
```

O atalho `\b` significa ["fronteira de palavra"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), e garante que antes do `Z` não há um caractere alfanumérico. Assim, a regex só pegará palavras que comecem com "Z".

Depois não ficou claro o que pode ter na palavra, mas eu usei `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` (uma ou mais letras ou números), seguido de outro `\b`. O resultado é um array de *matches*, e percorrendo-o, você tem as palavras encontradas:

```
ZANO
ZMES
ZDIA
```

---

Lembrando que a regex acima só considera palavras que comecem com a letra Z maiúscula. Se quiser considerar tanto maiúscula quanto minúscula, pode adicionar a *flag* `i`, que torna a regex *case insensitive*:

```
$texto = "SUZANO ZANO ZMES zDia ZANO_MES";
if (preg_match_all('/\bZ[A-Z0-9]+\b/i', $texto, $resultados)) {
    foreach($resultados[0] as $str) {
        echo "$str\n";
    }
}
```

Como agora a regex é *case insensitive*, eu pude usar apenas `[A-Z0-9]` (não é necessário colocar o intervalo `a-z` nesse caso). Agora ela pega palavras que comecem com "Z" ou "z":

```
ZANO
ZMES
zDia
```

---

#### Por que sua regex não funcionou

Sua primeira tentativa usa `[^A-Z]` (qualquer caractere que não seja uma letra de `A` a `Z`). A ideia foi boa, mas o problema é que esta expressão corresponde a um caractere, e este caractere fará parte do *match*. No caso da sua string, o espaço que existe antes do Z também será pego pela regex.

Depois você usou `[A-Z0-9^_]`. O caractere `^` dentro de colchetes só nega os caracteres se ele estiver logo depois do `[` (como ele está no meio, então ele corresponde ao próprio caractere `^`). Então esta regex não está excluindo o `_`, e sim incluindo-o.

Mas na verdade não precisa disso, pois os colchetes já são restritivos por si só, então se você fizesse apenas `[A-Z0-9]`, isso já excluiria o `_` (na verdade, isso já exclui qualquer caractere que não seja letra ou número).

A sua segunda tentativa também exclui os espaços antes do "Z", o que significa que não encontrará nenhuma ocorrência ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/s6X00Z/1/)).

Comment: Ficou perfeito, eu não sabia da utilização do \b. Grato pelo apoio !!!